# Find the derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=2$ if $f(x)=x^2 + x + \ln x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I'm fairly confused with this question (or I guess the concept of inverse functions and taking their derivative). I know that the general rule for taking the derivative of an inverse function is:

$$f^{-1}{'}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

But I'm not really sure where to go from here. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use the formula you wrote and consider $f(1)$.

Comment: Hmm..interesting. $f(1) = 2$, therefore $f^{-1}(2)=1$ , right? Then I can plug into my formula, and I get $f'^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(1)}$. I solve for $f'(1)$ and get 4 in the denominator, so the answer should be $\frac14$ . Did I go wrong anywhere?

Comment: Yes this is the correct idea.

Comment: That is right. But always check if your function is increasing or decreasing on its definition set. Also in the function you wrote the first assessment is $f^{-1'}$ and not  $f^{'-1}$

Answer (score 3):

First :
$f(1)=1+1+0=2$ and if you derivate f you can easily show that it is strictly positive (i.e. increasing) so $1$ is the only value such that $f(1)=2$.

so

$$f^{-1'}(2) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}= \frac{1}{f'(1)}=\frac{1}{2\cdot1+1+\frac{1}{1}}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Yeah, the math makes sense, although I'm not quite sure why/how you decided to use x=1.

Comment: I looked at the function and decided it would be really difficult to write $f^{-1}$ for all $x$. So I checked if the solution was not obvious and it was.

Comment: So you mean that you just looked at $f(x)$ and saw quickly that $x=1$ would give you the $2$ we needed to plug in something for $f^{-1}(x)$? What would you do if it wasn't obvious?

Comment: Yes. If it was not so obvious I would have graph it and look if there is a simple answer and try it (1/2, -1 etc.) because I saw that it is difficult to reverse. By the way, you can graph it in google by simply typing : y=x^2+x+ln(x)

Comment: Looking for obvious answer is a good reflex in general, for example to reduce polynomials (look for 1 0 -1) etc.